# How to clear console in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, mongo-shell

While using Mongodb console or shell sometimes my screen is cluttered with a lot of previous output which I do not need. So, is there a function to clear console in MongoDB?

Something like an analog of clear in MatLab.

I have tried `clc`, `clear` but with no success.

Comment: "cls" works for me in the shell

Answer (score 155, accepted):

Judging by [Jira](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-2533?page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels:all-tabpanel) they have done it: You need to write `cls` in the shell.

You can also use a hotkey: <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>L</kbd>.

In macOS: <kbd>Command</kbd> + <kbd>K</kbd>.

Check more hotkeys for the shell [here](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/mongo-shell/#keyboard-shortcuts).

Comment: in macOS Big Sur I use `cmd + L` to clear the screen.

Answer (score 70):

If you are using MongoDB 2.0 or higher, the `mongo` shell supports both:

- `cls` command
- `Ctrl+l` (clear screen)

Note that both of these clear the screen and put the cursor at the top .. but you can still scrollback to see previous history.

In OS X Terminal.app you can also do:

- `Command+K` (clear scrollback)

Clearing the screen and/or scrollback buffer are independent of the history, so you can still cursor up/down to run previous commands.

Comment: The `mongo` shell also supports other [Keyboard Editing Shortcuts](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/mongo-shell/#keyboard-shortcuts) similar to those found in Emacs or the `bash` shell.