# clear console (shell) in Redis

Tags: redis

Is there a way to clear Redis shell (Redis-cli) from the output of the previous commands?

Basically I need completely the same action like I have answered in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13327218/1090562), but instead MongoDB I need it for Redis.

P.S. I tried `clc`, `cls`, `clear`, `CTR + L` but as you understood with no results.

Comment: Just press `Enter` and hold it for five seconds :)

Comment: Does not work for windows. I was expecting a new fresh screen. Didn't get one.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

On terminals supported by Linenoise (used in redis-cli), both clear and CTRL-L work fine. It does with my ssh connection. Linenoise implements clear screen in the following way:

```
void linenoiseClearScreen(void) {
    if (write(STDIN_FILENO,"\x1b[H\x1b[2J",7) <= 0) {
        /* nothing to do, just to avoid warning. */
    }
}
```

So I guess this sequence does not work on your terminal ... or perhaps, you are using a very old version of redis-cli?

Comment: Not works under windows. compiled by cygwin use offical source.